# conditionally aggregate columns using tidyverse for large time series dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

After looking at a few other asked questions, and reading a few guides, I'm not able to find a suitable solution to my specific problem. Here's an example of the data to begin:

```
data <- data.frame(
        Date = sample(c("1993-07-05", "1993-07-05", "1993-07-05", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-08-30", "1993-09-04", "1993-09-04")),
        Site = sample(c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")),
        Station = sample(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2")),   
        Oxygen = sample(c("0.9", "0.4", "4.2", "5.6", "7.3", "4.3", "9.5", "5.3", "0.3")))
```

I want to average all the oxygen values for the stations that are nested within a site that corresponds to a date. My dataset has a couple of thousand rows, and like in the example, there are an uneven number of stations, and the dates are uneven in length.

The output I'm looking for are columns like, "Date -> Site -> Average Oxygen", foregoing the need for a station column altogether in the new version of the time series.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'Site', 'Date', get the `mean` of 'Oxygen' (after converting it to `numeric` - it is `factor` column)

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
   summarise(AverageOxygen = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Oxygen))))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Site [1]
#  Site  Date       AverageOxygen
#  <fct> <fct>              <dbl>
#1 1     1993-07-05          3.97
#2 1     1993-08-30          5.2 
#3 1     1993-09-04          2.55
```

Comment: Hi, I was just checking the math and it seems like the values are off? For "1993-07-05", the average of Stations 1,2,3 for that day is 1.83. I don't think the code takes into account that the Stations correspond to the day as well?

Comment: @SecretBeach. You have a `sample` data without a `set.seed`.  So your data might be different than mine

Comment: Oh, that's true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(hablar)
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  retype() %>% 
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  summarize(AverageOxygen = mean(Oxygen))
```

which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Site [?]
   Site Date       AverageOxygen
  <int> <date>             <dbl>
1     1 1993-07-05          4.7 
2     1 1993-08-30          3.55
3     1 1993-09-04          4.75
```

Comment: Hi, I was just checking the math and it seems like the values are off? For "1993-07-05", the average of Stations 1,2,3 for that day is 1.83. I don't think the code takes into account that the Stations correspond to the day as well?